# How to find word with subscript?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Input: `s = "test1 this is a sample subscript o₁"`

I've tried: `re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b').findall(s)`

It finds the word with more than 2 chars and doesn't contain number 
`'this', 'is', 'sample', 'subscript', 'o₁'`,

but it still has the subscript number.

Is there a way to remove word that contains subscript in it?

Desire output: `'this', 'is', 'sample', 'subscript'`

Comment: The point is that the Unicode aware `\d` in Python 3 regex does not match `No` Unicode category. You should exclude it "manually", add them to the negated character class.

Comment: Complementing the comment above, take a look at [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to build your expression based on matching letters, rather than matching anything other than `\W\d_` and some other stuff?

Comment: @khelwood `[a-zA-Z]` only matches ASCII letters. `[\W\d_]` is usually used as any letter matching regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But evidently that doesn't produce the right result for this.

Comment: Well, if only ASCII letter words are expected, then `re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b').findall(s)` is the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the Unicode aware `\d` in Python 3 regex does not match [`No` Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm).

If you need to work with ASCII only letter words, use

```
r'\b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b'
```

Or, make the pattern non-Unicode aware by using `re.A` / `re.ASCII` flag:

```
re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b', re.A)
```

See [this Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/8ixspk).

If you need to work with any Unicode letters you may fix it by either adding all the `No` characters to the regex negated character class (which might make it a tedious solution), or add a programmatic check after a match is found to see if the match contains any char from the `No` category.

See [this Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/t3mRj5):

```
import re, sys, unicodedata
s = "test1 this is a sample subscript o₁"
No = [chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)) == 'No']
print([x for x in re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b', s) if not any(y in x for y in No)])
# => ['this', 'is', 'sample', 'subscript']
```

Make sure you are using the latest Python version to support the latest Unicode standard, or rely on the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
p = regex.compile(r"\b\p{L}{2,}\b")
print(p.findall(s))
```

Comment: Can the ASCII flag: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII be used in the answer in any capacity?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes, if you plan to only work with ASCII, use `re.A`, or a more verbose `[A-Za-z]` based regex.